# How do I move string characters into the AL register in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
sTxt EQU <"AB", 0>
sTxtTwo EQU <"CD", 0>
sTxtThree EQU <"EF", 0>
.data
sO BYTE sTxt
.code
mov al, sO
main proc


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

I'm trying to move `sO`'s contents into the `al` register. How would I do this all the way (like all characters pretty much)?

Am I doing it right?

Comment: Right now, you're loading the first character. Repeat to get the others.

Comment: Would I just retype in mov al, sO for it to add the other characters? Thanks!

Comment: No, you aren't.  You put your load before the start of your `main` function where it won't run.  You also need a pointer or index in a register you can increment.